# Question about multiplication/divisions of logarithms

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, complex-multiplication

While solving the following logarithm question:
           $\frac{\log_3 135}{\log_{15} 3}\ - \frac{\log_3 5}{\log_{405} 3}\\$
I came to the point where I have to multiply two equal log:
           $\log_3 135.\log_3 15 - \log_3 5.\log_3 405$.
Is there any way to multiply two log.

Comment: you can simplify this quite a lot

Comment: I had tried it for more than an hour. Please gave a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_3 135.\log_3 15 - \log_3 5.\log_3 405=? $$

Note that $$135=5(27)\implies \log_3 135 =3+ \log_35 $$

Similarly $$\log_3 15= 1+\log_3 5 $$ and so forth.